# What Is It Called When You Tried to Write a Sound That Comes From a Person?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Here's an example:

> *The lady grasped the girl with her right hand. "**Gahhh!"** the girl screamed.*

What figure of speech would "Gahhh!" be classified as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [University of Ottawa](https://arts.uottawa.ca/writingcentre/en/hypergrammar/the-parts-of-speech) (but it's the same across all grammar sources I've looked at—I just happened to pick this one), "traditional grammar classifies words based on eight parts of speech: the verb, the noun, the pronoun, the adjective, the adverb, the preposition, the conjunction, and **the interjection** [emphasis mine]."

[**Interjection**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interjection):

> 2 : an ejaculatory utterance usually lacking grammatical connection: such as
> a : a word or phrase used in exclamation (such as *Heavens! Dear me!*)
> b : a cry or inarticulate utterance (such as *Alas! ouch! phooey! ugh!*) expressing an emotion
>
> a chorus of angry *interjections* greeted the announcement that our flight would be delayed

Answer (score 2):

**onomatopoeia** is the formation of a word that mimics what it sounds like, eg. 'boom'

Comment: It sounds odd to classify onomatopoeia as a *figure of speech*, but I may be wrong. Would you mind linking to some material that establishes that classification?

Comment: ["While some onomatopoeic words may be used as interjections, most interjections do not imitate sounds."](https://www.ereadingworksheets.com/figurative-language/poetic-devices/onomatopoeia-examples/) I imagine the original question will need to be clarified. Is it only talking about the specific type of utterances as given, or does it also include other utterances that do not fall into the onomatopoeia camp?

Answer (score 1):

You could be looking for **exclamation**, "a sudden cry or remark".

But, an exclamation can also include actual words.  "Hey you!" would be an example.